# Is this synchronized block needed or not?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized-block

For this code in a multiple thread environment, is the synchronized(c) necessary?

```
SynchronizedCounter c = new SynchronizedCounter();
synchronized(c){
   c.increment();
   c.value();
}

public class SynchronizedCounter {
   private int c = 0;

   public synchronized void increment() {
     c++;
    }
   public synchronized void decrement() {
     c--;
   }
   public synchronized int value() {
     return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using AtomicInteger

Answer (score 1):

It is **needed** if you want to make sure that when you call `c.value()` after `c.increment();` you are getting the `value + 1`

To avoid the situation that another `thread2` calls `c.decrement()` between the call of `c.increment()` and `c.value()` in `thread1`

Comment: So generally if a thread needs to call multiple methods in a sequence on an object and don't want other threads to interfere with it during that process, it should use local synchronization on individual object, regardless of whether the methods in that object are already sychronized or not. Is my understanding true?

Comment: you can synchronize on individual operations like you did in each method, but that's not the same as creating a block of operations to be done without interference.

Comment: Synchronizing a method or a block ensures that it will be executed at once without interference from another thread. But to ensure this behavior on a group of `synchronized methods` you still need synchronization for the entire code block.

Comment: Then what about this situation?  Suppose: c.increment() by Thread A, then a number of other operations occurs which have nothing to do with object c. Then finally c.value() at the end of the block. The two operations are not strictly in sequence. In this case, is it needed to put the big chunk of code in between c.increment() and c.value() in a synchonized block?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, if the two operations are not `racing` on a shared resource `c` in this example, so no need for synchronization

Comment: So in this sense, there is no real "thread safe" class. External synchronization may be needed always.

Comment: Hi, iTech, just assume Thread A needs to execute c.increment() and c.value() in a block, and it's unpredictable that other threads might take what actions on object C. So to be thread safe, the block sync is always needed. That's my question! Thanks.

Comment: You should be aware that synchronization could decrease the program performance and create a bottleneck. So it should be used wisely when needed only.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the getValue call to see the result of the increment, without intervening increment or decrement from another thread, you do need the synchronized(c).

This is a sufficiently common requirement that similar designs often return the new value from an increment or decrement call. See, for example, [java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). It has methods such as     incrementAndGet().

Incidentally, if you are really using this code, rather than just using it to illustrate your question, consider using AtomicInteger instead.